# Jasper Server error 'Crosstab bucket/measure limit (100,000) exceeded.'

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have create a report in jasper server with cross tab component. But when previewing the the report it gives this error message(`Crosstab bucket/measure limit (100,000) exceeded`.). How can I avoid this error.
Note: I haven't add any filter or input control to the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is:

> The governor threshold given as an integer number representing the
>   maximum number of cells multiplied by the number of measures in the
>   generated crosstab limit.

You need to increase this limit by:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.crosstab.bucket.measure.limit
```

in the `jasperreports.properties`, that you will find under `webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/classes/`

If you set it to -1 the crosstab governer should become disabled but you will risk `OutOfMemory` error.

For more info see package info on [Crosstab governor](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/crosstabs/package-summary.html)